# Selecting cell in a specific sheet which has hide/unhide row macros

Tags: excel, vba, selection

I have a series of macros with the following format:

```vb
Sub EUCheck_Click()
If Range("EU_Tick").Value = "True" Then
    ActiveSheet.Rows("54:60").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else:
    ActiveSheet.Rows("54:60").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
End Sub
```

This works, however when I select a cell within this sheet it often selects a cell 8/9 cells up or down from the one I am trying to select.

I think this starts by selecting where the cell would be if the first 1/2 tick boxes were click and cells were hidden, however this gap between where I try and click and where is selected is then maintained.

Comment: `If Expression = True Then Boolean = True Else Boolean = False`... These redundant structures can be rewritten like `Boolean = Expression`. `ActiveSheet.Rows("54:60").EntireRow.Hidden = Not Range("EU_Tick").Value`

Comment: The `:` character is used in VBA as a [line continuation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/how-to-break-and-combine-statements-in-code#to-place-multiple-statements-on-the-same-line) character which allows you to put multiple statements in the same line for visual clarity in your code. You don't need it after `Else` and it can be removed.

Comment: It would help to see the code that is actually causing you problems. But often in Excel using `Selection` and `Activate` in your code is unreliable and the sub-optimal way of locating the data or objects you want to interact with. I suggest changing from `Select` to just directly referencing the ranges you want to target using the full object path like `Application.Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")`. You will never target the wrong cell if you are fully specifying the location like this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in VBA. Selections count hidden Row numbers even if you cannot access them. The best workaround is the comment of Toddleson.

Another solution is to show all Rows at the beginning with `Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False` and hide all relevant rows at once at the end of your macro.

I faced the same problem in MS Project since there is no way to use paths. The solution for MS project is `Application.FilterClear` and `Application.OutlineShowAllTasks`.